# Asignación de Valores, con respecto a Fechas largas con horas y minutos usando vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito asignarle al primer cuadro el peso de acuerdo al rango del segundo cuadro. usando VBA en excel...Ayuda!!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es esta imagen, muestro como debería de quedar, son para 10000 celdas. No es necesario que se coloree el peso.

El objetivo es que para la tabla N°1 se pueda colocar los pesos de acuerdo a su fecha, comparándola con la tabla N°2 rango de fechas el cual ya tiene un peso y ese peso debería colocarse automáticamente en la tabla N°1

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Por favor, pon un ejemplo de cómo debería quedar tras usar VBA. Si no, es difícil ayudarte. Explica la lógica que hay detrás del proceso, con detalles.

Comment: Hola, ya coloque una foto de como debería de quedar. agradecería bastante tu ayuda!

Comment: Vale, solo una duda. Si el dato en la primera columna fuera, por ejemplo, 01/01/2018 05:30:00, ¿qué peso se le asignaría? ¿3685 o 3710?

Comment: Y otra pregunta. ¿Es obligatorio que lo hagas en VBA? ¿No te valen fórmulas normales?

Comment: 01/01/2018 05:30:00 el valor seria 3685 y si fuera 01/01/2018 05:31:00 el valor seria 3710. si, me valen cualquier método, lo importante es poder asignar estos valores a toda mi hoja en el excel....gracias por tu apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Para esta operación, necesitas utilizar fórmulas matriciales, es decir, metes la fórmula como siempre, pero en vez de presionar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> para confirmar, tienes que meterla presionando <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

> Sabrás que has introducido la fórmula en forma matricial si aparecen
>   `{` y `}` al principio y final de tu fórmula.

Y otra ocsa más. **Esta fórmula solamente funcionará si las fechas son fechas de verdad. Si tienen formato texto, no funcionará.**

Yo he replicado a mano tu situación (para tu próxima pregunta, te sugiero que, aparte de imágenes, pongas también los datos para copiar y pegar).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula que he utilizado es la siguiente:

```
=INDICE($G$2:$G$4;COINCIDIR(MIN(SI($F$2:$F$4>=A2;$F$2:$F$4));$F$2:$F$4;0);1)
```

Básicamente, lo que hace la fórmula es una matriz con las fechas finales que sean igual o mayor a la fecha de referencia. De esa matriz, se queda con la fecha más baja (usamos MIN). Una vez que tiene la fecha final correcta, entonces con COINCIDIR obtenemos su fila en la tabla, y con ÍNDICE extraemos el peso equivalente a dicha fecha.

Tendrás que adaptar los rangos de la fórmula a tus necesidades.

Espero que te pueda servir. A mí me funciona perfectamente. Ya nos contarás.

Comment: Gracias!!!, voy a probarlo